# Sanity- stuck on 'Linking Dependencies'

Tags: sanity

Every time I try to initiate a sanity project, it gets stuck on 'linking dependencies'. Doesn't matter if I use a pre-made sanity or start a new one. Using npm, not yarn. It just doesn't finish, no matter how long I wait.

Does anyone know why, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try too manually install the packages with `npm i` or `yarn`